# Find locations that are behind my current location in Android

Tags: android, gps, location

I have some locations (lat & long) and I need to show these locations in a listview. I can do this perfectly.

But now I want to show the locations that are ahead of my current location. That means I want to skip the locations that I have already passed during my driving.

Let me clarify more clearly. we have locations like loc1 (lat,lon) , loc2(lat,lon), loc3(lat,lon).. loc100 (lat,lon). during my driving I like to see the locations (loc1 - loc100). But now I want to hide the locations (between loc1 to loc100) which I have passed from my current position/location. Say, I have passed loc1, loc3, loc5 so I need to skip these 3 locations from my listing in listview. To achieve this, I need to know which locations (loc1 - loc100) are behind my current location (gps current location) so that I can skip that locations.

Any idea? how i can achieve this in my code? Please help regarding this.

Comment: DO these (lat,longs) you have show a path...  may be way to a destination?

Comment: basically I have some locations (lat & lon) and showing these locations during driving. but now want that as I am driving, I don't need to show the locations that I have already passed. here I have no chance to use map, it is a listview. Any idea?

Comment: your question is not specific. you want the driver to pass the exact location say (lat1,long1) or a nearby area, or just crossed the latitude/longitude... which locations do you want to hide. Please specify.

Comment: okay, let me clarify. we have locations like loc1 (lat,lon) , loc2(lat,lon), loc3(lat,lon).. loc100 (lat,lon). during my driving I like to see the locations (loc1 - loc100). But now I want to hide the locations (between loc1 to loc100) which I have passed from my current position/location. Say, I have passed loc1, loc3, loc5 so I need to skip these 3 locations from my listing in listview. To achieve this, I need to know which locations (loc1 - loc100) are behind my current location (gps current location) so that I can skip that locations. Clear about my problem?

Comment: your problem is still not clear, but let me give you a simple solution from what I understand. Keep a threshold say 100 meters, check phone's location say every 30sec. After you get the location, see if it is in range (as specified 100 mtr range) of any of the loc1-100 (a simple loop). if it is, recreate your list view adapter, but this time avoid the location you passed. Save this location (or location index) in Shared preference or SQLite DB. Keep saving these locations  (call it a reject list) as the phone moves. Refresh you adapter and recreate listview. You should mention 30 sec & 100 m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have two data structures (e.g., LinkedList) of Location objects:

- unvisitedLocations
- visitedLocations

Your list being shown to the user would be based on the contents of the unvisitedLocations data structure.

Based on your real-time location, you will need to detect proximity to each of the Location objects in the unvisitedLocations data structure based on given radius threshold value that you choose.  To do this, you can either register each location with the LocationManager.addProximityAlert() methods (which will fire a PendingIntent when detecting proximity), or loop through the unvisitedLocations data structure and do this on your own - something like:

```
if(currentLocation.distanceTo(unvisitedLocations[i]) < threshold){
    visitedLocations.add(unvisitedLocations[i]);        
    unvisitedLocations.remove(i);
}
```

This will give you the list of currently visited and unvisitedLocations based on your real-time locations.

Note that as initial size of the unvisitedLocations grows, performance will become an issue since you'd be looping through the entire data structure contents to determine proximity of location for each real-time location update, which can be once per second from GPS.  If performance becomes an issue, you should look into moving the proximity detection server-side and using a spatial database, which has special data structures to make proximity detection far less intensive.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I like it. I have no option to use server side, so if I go with your visited/unvisited data structure and use gps min time is 2 minutes, then it will be good at preformance. what do you think?

Comment: Depends on how many unvisited locations you are tracking.  I would think around 50 when monitoring GPS every few seconds would still have reasonable performance on a mid-to-high-end Android device, but you'll want to test on real devices, if at all possible, before you make your app available to the public.  With a 2 min GPS update rate, you could probably go upwards of 1000 locations without having a huge impact on the device - again testing is important.  Be careful with the threshold value - with 2 min. GPS update rate you'll need a large threshold to avoid missing detection of visitation.